# Semicolon tab stop in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, tabs, vb6-migration

In VB6, there was a function that moves the print position along to the next tabstop, like so:

```
Print #1, "Total run time: "; _
                Fix(tmpTick / 60000) & " min and " _
                & Fix((Abs((tmpTick / 60000) - Fix(tmpTick / 60000)) _
                * 60)) & " Sec"
```

I have rewritten this VB6 into VB.NET, but with the semicolon still intact:

```
 mainoutputwriter.WriteLine("Total run time: "; _
                Fix(tmpTick / 60000) & " min and " _
                & Fix((Abs((tmpTick / 60000) - Fix(tmpTick / 60000)) _
                * 60)) & " Sec")
```

What do I replace the semicolon with to move the print position?

Thanks

Comment: Semicolon prints the next item adjacent to the last, COMMA is used to tab.

Comment: Oh.. How can I recreate this in VB.net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ControlChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars.aspx) class is probably what you want to use.

Try replacing the semicolon with `ControlChars.Tab`.

Comment: Although, I appear to have hit a bit of a wall. In the old Print # statements, there were SPC(**) functions, but they won't work with the ControlChars.Tab thing, it complains:
mainoutputwriter.WriteLine(SPC(23) ControlChars.Tab & "Mould Flux")
even with , or & inbetween, or combinations of both. Have you any advice?

Comment: @Nick I "think" the SPC function is now "new string(' '), 23)"